# Merge [member-function] and [member-functions] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Unless there is something weird I'm missing, there seems to be no point in having both a [member-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-function) and a [member-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-functions) tag. I believe these should be merged.

Comment: I'd vote for the plural form, [tag:member-functions], being the master tag. The fact that it has more questions seems to confirm my preference.